# Ubuntu 11.04 wireless driver not detected

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, wifi

When I run `iwconfig` I get:

> no wireless extensions

How do I get Ubuntu to detect my wireless driver?

Looking at the output from `lspci` and `lsusb`, here's the relevant line, from `lsusb` (so it's a USB wifi and bluetooth device):

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 03f0:171d Hewlett-Packard Wireless (Bluetooth + WLAN) Interface [Integrated Module]
```

Comment: I fear this depends on your wireless hardware. Could you give the relevant part of `lspci`, or `lsusb` and `dmesg` output when you connect the device?

Comment: lspci: http://hermanningjaldsson.com/1

Comment: lsusb: http://hermanningjaldsson.com/2

Comment: and i mean, i dont really connect the device, its just in there somewhere.

Comment: Ok so the relevant part must be `Hewlett-Packard Wireless (Bluetooth + WLAN) Interface [Integrated Module]`, the device is attached to the usb controller. If ubuntu can't find a driver for it that's bad news. Couldn't find something useful using google, but maybe you should try.

Comment: The cards ID doesn't show up in this list:  http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Devices/USB  (probably won't work)

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 must provide support for wireless somehow, its gotta be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a broadcom-based module. Here's what I've found for it:

```
apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

Suggestion comes [from here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=59567).

Comment: Nice catch. With some luck this might be enough to make it work!